# Android Studio java incorrect display TextView

Tags: java, android, android-intent, textview

I understand that my question is probably not difficult, but I could not find an answer to it. In a nutshell: I transfer text between activities through an intent. In the second activity, instead of text, I get the following. I have used intent more than once to transfer data between activities and there have never been such problems.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2OKn.png)

Comment: When you put the extra in the `Intent`, you inadvertently called `toString()` directly on the `TextView`, instead of on its text; e.g., `textView.getText().toString()`.

Answer (score 1):

from sender activity

```
    String textToSend = someTextView.getText().toString();
    Intent intent = Intent(this, ReceiverActivity.java);
    intent.putExtra("text", textToSend);
    startActivity(intent);
```

you're currently sending textview as string instead of text from the textview

Comment: omg... i forgot to add getText()... its look like String s = someTextView.toString... thank u so mutch...!!

Comment: nice... happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are passing data as string and also when you retrieve in second activity, use "getStringExtra()" method and define a string variable and use

val stringdata = intent.getStringExtra("your_intent_name")